# extract month from mysql

Tags: mysql, date

How can I extract the month with a sql query in mysql. 
The date format is as follows: dd/mm/yyyy.

```
MONTH(datecol) = $month // this does not work.
```

However if I change the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` it works, but this is not an option.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be an option ? o_o

Comment: If I said it's not an option it's not an option simple as that. We dont control the flow of data into the database only when it has been written.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse a date in any format into an SQL date value with [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). For example:

```
select month(str_to_date('25/07/2013', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```

Comment: This seems safer than @spencer7593's suggestion since you're explicitly defining the date format.

Comment: Can I bake this into my current query? "SELECT Dest FROM tbldata WHERE site = $site"; ?

Comment: You can include it in any query, but I don't see how it fits in the particular query you quote. Where's the date from which you want to extract the month?

Answer (score 3):

This expression will extract the portion of the string that appears between the first and second forward slashes.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '25/07/2013' ,'/',2),'/',-1)
```

will return `'07'`

To get this converted to a numeric, add zero to it,

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( '25/07/2013' ,'/',2),'/',-1) + 0
```

will return a numeric value of `7`

---

**NOTES**

This expression will work with any string value, not just strings representing a valid date in the specified format. For example:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'dd/mm/yyyy' ,'/',2),'/',-1)
```

will return `'mm'`

If only one slash is found in the string, this will return the portion following the slash. If no slashes are found in the string, this will return the entire string.

If your intent is to validate that the string represents a valid date value, in the specified format, then the `STR_TO_DATE()` function can be used to convert the string to a `DATE`. The return from that expression can be used as an argument to any of the MySQL functions that take a `DATE` argument, such as the `MONTH()` function in your sample question.